# Unit tests using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to unit tests and well, I'm struggling to understand how it should be done.
I have some methods with @RequestParam and I'm not sure how to mock this.
It would be great if I had an example I could apply to the other methods.

Could you help me by writing the test method for this one? It would be very useful.

```
    @PutMapping("/player/update-password")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updatePlayerPassword(@RequestParam("token") String token, @RequestParam("password") String newPassword) throws URISyntaxException {
        String message = bundle.getString("put_player");
        log.debug(message, token, newPassword);
        PlayerEntity player = playerService.updatePassword(token, newPassword);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(PlayerMapper.INSTANCE.mapPlayer(player), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to mock everything which is not directly created in your controller, e.g. the `playerService` should be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations. With it you can inject mocks to your controller.

```
@Mock
PlayerService playerServiceMock;
```

And use `when().then()` from Mockito inside test or method with `@Before` annotation:

```
when(playerServiceMock.updatePassword(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(playerEntity);
```

The same can be done for `bundle.getString("put_player")`.

Comment: Yes, but I would recommend using doReturn(playerEntity).when(playerServiceMock).updatePassword(EXPECTED_LOGIN, EXPECTED_PASSWORD) approach it's more powerful especially if @Spy is used and unify the test style in such cases. Second thing, I would avoid to use anyString() just particular Strings constants to avoid false positive tests.

Comment: Actually my question was about those @RequestParam. How should I handle them?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are using the Mockito. You can try the below code, need to add all imports

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class YourClassNameTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    YourClassName yourClassName;

    @Mock
    PlayerService playerService;

    @Before
    public void Setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourClassName);
    }

    @Test
    public void updatePlayerPasswordTest() throws Exception {

        PlayerEntity player = new PlayerEntity();
        // set some date if you want

        Mockito.when(playerService.updatePassword(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(player);

                RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/player/update-password?token=abc&password=test")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());      
    }
}
```